# Stretch - etc/network/interfaces deprecated - dhcpcd.conf not filling role?

Tags: networking

I've been trying to work through this all night, to no avail. I'm about ready to move back to Jessie.

Essentially, I'm trying to setup an auto-ppp interface (like I've done many times in Jessie) and usually, I'll just set this inside my /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto gprs
iface gprs inet ppp
provider gprs
```

However, I'm reading that in Stretch, `interfaces` is now obsolete. This poses a problem as now I cannot setup my interface and have it start automatically within dhcpcd.conf.

I feel as if I'm missing something - but I'm not sure what.

The end of my dhcpcd.conf:

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.0.1/24
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8

interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.1.155/24
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8
```

Comment: See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/75213/8697

Comment: I see, so is my best option here just to remove those two hooks and (10-wpa_supplicant) and continue to use the old /etc/network/interfaces?

Comment: Depends what else you have. There is another option, include `denyinterfaces gprs` in `dhcpcd.conf` (assuming the interface is still `gprs` under [predictable network interface names](https://www.debian.org/releases/stretch/amd64/release-notes/ch-whats-new.en.html#new-interface-names) ) See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/74905/8697